# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is divergent. Which of the following series are convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is
divergent. Which of the following series are convergent?

a.$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$

b.$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$

c.
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+ n^2a_n}$

**My Solution:-**

(a)Taking $a_n=n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{1+n}$ diverges.

(b) Taking $a_n=n$,  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{1+n^2}$ diverges using limit comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$

(c) $\frac{a_n}{1+n^2a_n}\leq \frac{a_n}{n^2a_n}=\frac{1}{n^2} $. Using comparison test. Series converges. I am not able to conclude for general case for (a) and (b)?

Comment: Your solution is enough as it is: (a), (b) are not (surely) convergent, (c) is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (b) the series could diverge as you showed or converge as with

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n = m^2 \\ \frac{1}{n^2}, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

since

$$\sum_{n= 1}^N \frac{a_n}{1+na_n} = \sum_{n \neq m^2} \frac{a_n}{1+na_n} + \sum_{n = m^2} \frac{a_n}{1+na_n} \\ \leqslant \sum_{n= 1}^N \frac{1}{n + n^2}+ \sum_{n= 1}^N \frac{1}{1+n^2}$$

For (a) the series **always** diverges.

Consider cases where $a_n$ is bounded and unbounded. If $a_n < B$ then $a_n/(1 + a_n) > a_n/(1+B)$ and we have divergence by the comparison test.

Try to examine the second case where $a_n$ is unbounded yourself. Hint: There is a subsequence $a_{n_k} \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a divergent series of positive real numbers prove that the
series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ is divergent.

Proof:
Let $S_n = a_1 +a_2 + ... +a_n$ .
Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a divergent series of positive real numbers, the
sequence $\{S_n\}$ is a monotone increasing sequence and $\lim S_n = \infty.$
Therefore for every natural number $n$ we can choose a natural number
$p$ such that $S_{n+p} > 1 + 2S_{n}$ . Now, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{1+a_{n+1}}+\frac{a_{n+2}}{1+a_{n+2}}+....+\frac{a_{n+p}}{1+a_{n+p}} >\frac{a_{n+1}}{1+S_{n+1}}+\frac{a_{n+2}}{1+S_{n+2}}+....+\frac{a_{n+p}}{1+S_{n+p}}$ (since  $S_{n+p}\ge S_{n+1}\ge a_{n+1}$....$S_{n+p}\ge a_{n+p}$)

Now $\frac{a_{n+1}}{1+S_{n+1}}+\frac{a_{n+2}}{1+S_{n+2}}+....+\frac{a_{n+p}}{1+S_{n+p}}= \frac{S_{n+p}-S_n}{1+S_{n+p}}>\frac{\frac{1}{2}(1+S_{n+p})}{1+S_{n+p}}=\frac{1}{2}$
This shows that Cauchy's principle of convergence is not satisfied by
the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ Hence the series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

a. Use the $n$-th term test. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}=1$, regardless of whether $a_n$ increases without bound or is bounded. Because this is not equal to 0, it must diverge.

Better b.

Use the limit comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{na_n}{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$. The limit comparison test, if applied correctly, gives a limit of 1, which satisfies the conditions. Because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ diverges, the other series must diverge.

Keep in mind that the fact that the $a_n$ sum diverges was not used.

Comment: what if $a_n = 1/n$?

Comment: I fixed that with the new solution

Comment: The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$ need not be $1$. If $a_n \to 0$, then the limit is $0$.